# Can I display 2 items at a time using the onload function -Javascript ?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onload

I use the  onload function to show the date when the page is opened, and it' working correctly. 
But when I added the username to this  function, it doesn't display anything (I want the username to be displayed at the top of the page too.)

This is the function I'm using:

```
    window.onload = function () {
    var newDate = new Date();
    $('#dateday').val(newDate.getFullYear() + '-' + newDate.getMonth() + '-' + newDate.getDate()); // This is showed correctly 
    alert(localStorage["username"]); // It's alerted correctly
    $('#usernamethename').val(localStorage["username"]); //This is not displayed.
```

The html code:

```
    <h3 id="usernamethename"></h3>
    <input id="dateday" type= text></input>
```

Do you know why isn't the username displayed ? & if there are any better ideas to show the name at the top the page, I'd really appreciate it if you mentioned them.

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#usernamethename').text(localStorage["username"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

do this

```
$('#usernamethename').html(localStorage["username"]);
```